# Why does this not work? "ls *.txt | xargs cat > all.txt" (all files into single txt document)

Tags: pipe, cat, xargs

Why does this not work?

```
ls *.txt | xargs cat > all.txt
```

(I want to join the contents of all text files into a single 'all.txt' file.)
find with -exec should also work, but I would really like to understand the xargs syntax.

Thanks

Comment: Though [don't use `ls` for this](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If you really can't use `cat *.txt >all.txt` then try `printf '%s\0' *.txt | xargs -r0 cat >all` and then `mv all all.txt` to avoid having the file referencing itself.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`ls *.txt | xargs cat >> all.txt`

might work a bit better, since it would append to all.txt instead of creating it again after each file.

By the way, `cat *.txt >all.txt` would also work. :-)

Comment: The cat *.txt >all.txt is naturally better. Thanks

Comment: However, the ... | xargs cat >> all.txt or > all.txt always return error with xargs: unmatched single quote ...
Is it because xargs takes everything after it as the command?

Comment: Do you have filenames with spaces? If so, then use something like "find /your/path -iname '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 cat >>all.txt" instead

Comment: no, I replaced all the filename spaces with _.
But thinking of it, some filenames are likely to include single quotes as in listing_O'Connor_.txt, this might be the problem!

Comment: Yes, that's the problem then. :) The easiest and the sanest way is to use find with -print0 combined with xargs -0 -- then the whole chain will use NULL character as a separator and whitespace and special characters will be taken care of automatically.

Comment: Indeed:
After removing the single-quotes in some filenames via "s/'/_/g" *.txt, the command works OK!!
But could it be done from within xargs via some option???

Comment: OK, find isn't bad either... I remember having similar problems when the file names contained spaces!!

Comment: find is much better than ls in case you need to recurse into subdirectories.

Comment: for the latter: what about ls -R? (apart from the directory line?!)

Comment: ls -R maybe fine for human readable form, but if you need to handle something with xargs or other tools -- not so much. See, ls -R does not list the full path along with the every filename, but find or tree will do it. Makes scripting a lot easier. When scripting or piping stuff, please get rid of ls and use more advanced tools :-)

Comment: This is potentially very dangerous command. If "all.txt" already exists, running this command will expand to fill all available hard drive space.

Answer (score 3):

If some of your file names contain ', " or space `xargs` will fail because of [the separator problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs#Separator_problem)

In general never run `xargs` without -0 as it will come back and bite you some day.

Consider using GNU Parallel instead:

```
ls *.txt | parallel cat > tmp/all.txt
```

or if you prefer:

```
ls *.txt | parallel cat >> tmp/all.txt
```

Learn more about GNU Parallel http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Answer (score 1):

`all.txt` is a file in the same directory, so cat gets confused when it wants to write from the same file to the same file.

On the other hand:

```
ls *.txt | xargs cat > tmp/all.txt
```

This will read from textfiles in your current directory into the all.txt in a subdirectory (not included with `*.txt`).

Comment: Still the following error:
xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option

Comment: Do you have a .txt file  with a singlequote in its name?

Answer (score 0):

You could also come across a command line length limitation. Part of the reason for using `xargs` is that it splits up the input into safe command-line-sized chunks.  So, imagine a situation in which you have hundreds of thousands of .txt files in the directory.  `ls *.txt` will fail.  You would need to do

```
ls | grep .txt$ |xargs cat > /some/other/path/all.txt
```

`.txt$` in this case is a regular expression matching everything that ends in .txt (so it's not exactly like `*.txt`, since if you have a file called `atxt`, then `*.txt` would not match it, but the regular expression would.)

The use of another path is because, as other answers have pointed out, all.txt is matched by the pattern `*.txt` so there would be a conflict between input and output.

Note that if you have any files with `'` in their names (and this may be the cause of the `unmatched single quote` error), you would want to do

```
ls | grep --null .txt$ | xargs -0 cat > /some/other/path/all.txt
```

The --null option tells grep to use output separated by a `\0` (aka null) character instead of the default newline, and the `-0` option to `xargs tells it to expect its input in the same format.  This would work even if you had file names with newlines in them.